# Mosek Fusion APIs

Tags: optimization, api, mosek

Does anyone know if there is a list of available function APIs for Mosek Fusion APIs? Namely, what functions are available, their arguments list and meaning, what they do. Something similar to UNIX man pages or standard R or python API references.

Is there a way to convert a script based on Fusion APIs to its underlying Optimizer APIs? Essentially trying to understand how a simple formulation using Fusion APIs can be formulated equivalently using a lower level Optimizer APIs.

Answer (score 4):

The second line in the table at

https://www.mosek.com/documentation/

has all the Fusion manuals. For instance

https://docs.mosek.com/latest/pythonfusion/api-reference.html

is what you are looking for in the Python case. In any case we at Mosek are not aware of any other documentation.

A Fusion model cannot be converted to an optimizer API model automatically. You have to do that by hand. (Btw the overhead of Fusion is in most cases insignificant.)